# self parameter with int value

Tags: python, self, built-in

I'm trying to understand this code snippet who uses the built-in method `__call__` of a class. I added some prints and previously included an `__init__(self,n)` to understand the flow better, but the original code is only the `__call__` function.

I think I understand the major part but what confuses me is the behavior of the `self` argument, apparently related with the `int` inheritance. I don't know why when you get an instance of the class passing `n`, it not only receives `n` but implicitly updates the `self` variable to `n`.

To me `self` is a pointer like the C++ `this`, and I can't find the implicit "thing" who converts `n` in a new `self` value, or the reason why `self` is not an address.

This is the code.

```
class add(int):
    # def __init__(self,n):
    #     print("init: self = ", self)
    #     print("init: n    = ", n)
        
    def __call__(self,n):
        print("call: self = ", self)
        print("call: n    = ", n)
        return add(self+n)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = add(0)
    print("result variant a = ", a(5)(3)(1), "\n")    
    print("result variant b = ", add(5)(3)(1))
```

Comment: I suggest running the coe with a debugger and going line by line to see what is happenning.

Comment: `self` is nothing special or magical. It is merely the *first argument to an instance method, which is bound to the instance when called on an instance*. It acts *exactly* like any other argument to a function, and you can think of `some_instance.some_method()` as syntactic sugar for `SomeClass.some_method(some_instance)`. That's it. `self` is *not an address*. Variables are not addresses in Python. All variables act as references to objects.

Comment: So your `__call__` method *returns a new `add` object, the one created by `add(self+n)` and of course, `add` understands `+` because it inherits the implementation from `int`. And addition always creates a new `int` object, because `int` objects are immutable.

Comment: Basically, the reason `self` and `n` are both the same int object is because the first step of python object construction, the *actual constructor* is `__new__`, which calls `__init__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if self is an obj reference why in the case of int inheritance it return an int value and not a ref address? I mean how works the mechanism of implicit conversion to int? If I remove the inheritance then print(self) returns the usual message, in this case <__main__.add object at 0x7f94b0672668>. Is something like C++ operator overload?

Comment: @RobertGG what? *Everything* is a reference in Python. `int` objects **are objects** no different than a user defined object.

Comment: So, that `'<__main__.whatever object at 0x7f94b0672668>'` output is just the standard output from `object.__repr__`, `int.__repr__` overrides this with a method that prints the decimal integer representation of the `int` object.... so just check out `(32).__repr__()` ... of course, we can call the parent class method directly: `object.__repr__(32)`